# androidx.room.InvalidationTracker eror while building the kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

error: androidx.room.InvalidationTracker needs to have either an empty constructor or a constructor that takes Database as its only parameter. - androidx.room.InvalidationTracker
getting the above error while building the app with kotlin